Strange different behavior when single stepping into a java.lang.reflect.Method
Consider the following code:
Optional<Method> method = Arrays.stream(clazz.getMethods()).filter(m -> m.getName().equals("hello")).findFirst();
if (method.isPresent()) {
  method.get().invoke(instance);
}

When stepping (debugging) into the invoke method above in IntelliJ IDEA, I find myself in method java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke. However for the following (slightly changed) code:
Optional<Method> method = Arrays.stream(clazz.getMethods()).filter(m -> m.getName().equals("hello")).findFirst();
if (method.isPresent()) {
  Method m = method.get();
  m.invoke(instance);
}

I will be lead straight to the <instance>.hello method (which is what I actually want). The only difference is that method.get().invoke(instance) is split into two calls.
Can someone explain this strange different behavior?

Does your IntelliJ IDEA have a step filter feature and was it active? Otherwise, can you reproduce this with different debuggers? In the latter case, it would be useful to know which compiler has been used und which version and which JVM version you were using for debugging.

The difference happens because of how the debugger handles inlining.
In the first example, method.get().invoke(instance) is treated as one compound operation, so the debugger stops at Method.invoke. In the second example, splitting the call lets the debugger associate m.invoke(instance) directly with the target method (hello), so it steps into hello as expected.

You can read this content about method inlining: What is method inlining?

The compiler can optimize performance by replacing a function call with the actual code of the function itself, reducing the cost of calling the function at runtime.

Thank you, le dat. Does that mean that when debugging under "normal" circumstances Method.invoke(...) will always resolve to the actual method and not step into the reflection framework classes?

The first part of the answer just repeats what has been stated in the question without providing an actual explanation. The second part is just wrong. Inlining is an optimization done transparently to the application and the debugger. Even worse, there is no good reason why having the code split into two source code lines should influence the JVM’s optimizer (which doesn’t even know that the source code has two lines).

Ok, Holger. I am just interested in an explanation for the strange behavior, and the answer sounded plausible. Do you have another idea? Please let me know.

@JakobBjerreJensen it may only sound plausible at the first glance. The more you look at it, the less sense it makes. I’m interested in an explanation too, that’s why I asked you those questions
